# How to use WOL using mobile + PC with teamviewer and wake up the sleeping PC?

Tags: teamviewer, wake-on-lan

Mobile + Teamviewer functioning
WOL via rightclick on network card enabled, incl magic packet
In Bios PCI can wake from sleep
In OS keyboard and mouse can wake from sleep
PC+Monitor sleep after 1min all functioning well

What does not is, when the PC is at sleep and mobile and PC not connected via teamviewer, TV can not wake up the sleeping PC.

When connecting TV mobile+PC, PC does not go to sleep

What to do?

OS=win 10

Edit: Figured this only works with Public Address and DynDNS. So I've set up a free dns from my local selfhost.de company, have enabled in my router from my internet provider dyndns and entered all the selfhost.de data - What to do next? Data to add to the Ethernet connection under network settings which is using ipv4 and is by default empty? If so, which data - or what else to do to get this to work?

For example which public address do I need to enter into the WOL field "public address" which is empty and only port 9 is entered?

So far:

1. https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z7jXa.png
2. https://i.stack.imgur.com/jooFW.png
3. https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z25AC.png

http://www.test-ipv6.com/ also gives me an ipv4 address which differs from the LAN address. What to enter where please?

Comment: How to solve this?